# Adding language variable into WWW::Mailchimp (subscription)

Tags: perl, mailchimp

I'm trying to work out how I can use **WWW::Mailchimp** ( http://search.cpan.org/~arcanez/WWW-Mailchimp/ ) to sign someone up to our list, but also assign the language of the person (i.e english, french, german, spanish, etc).

Here is what I have thus far:

```
my $mailchimp = WWW::Mailchimp->new(apikey => 'xxxx' );
   $mailchimp->listSubscribe( id => "xxx", email_address => $in->{Email}, merge_vars => [ FNAME => $name[0], LNAME => $name[1], mc_language => "fr", LANG => "fr", LANGUAGE => "fr" ] );
```

**mc_language => "fr", LANG => "fr", LANGUAGE => "fr"** doesn't seem to do anything (been trying all the params I see laying around, in the vain hope one of them works!)

While it works (and asks you to confirm your subscription), all the language variables are ignored. Looking at their documents, I'm a bit confused as to what to use:

https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php

The code "fr" is ok, but I'm unsure what params to pass along to it.

Has anyone had any experience with this before? Apart from the language, it works fine (but I need to be able to send the confirmation emails in their own language, and then also filter down when doing mailings)

**UPDATE:** Ok, so it looks like its not going to be a simple case of updating to the newer API. I've been looking into the v3.0 API, and its a total overhaul of the older one (new function names, new ways of sending requests, etc). What I'm going to do is look into a "Curl" method, so we can at least get it going with that. Once I've got that going, I'll probably have a look at coding something to work with LWP::UserAgent, as that'd be cleaner than doing lots of curl requests. Shame there isn't anything out there already for Perl and MailChimp (with the new API, or even version 2.0!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got there in the end! I have been talking with MailChimp support, and they were very helpful. Turns out it was a double issue.

1) **Auto-Translate** needed to be enabled for the list in question. This was their answer around that:

> After taking a look at the call, it appears to be set up properly now, so you are all good on that front. That being said, I am seeing
>   that the Auto-translate option doesn't seem to be enabled for any of
>   your lists. In order for the Confirmation and all other response
>   emails to automatically translate, this will need to be enabled for
>   all of the lists being used.
>
> We have a bit of additional information on that, here, if you'd like to check that out:
>   http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/translate-signup-forms-and-emails#Auto-Translate-Forms

2) When making the request via the API, you need to specifically set the `Accept-Language: xx` value. For example, en, fr, es, de, etc.

Here is a working function for anyone who needs it in the future. Just be sure to update the apikey,listId and endpoint URL.

```
do_register_email_list('foo@bar.com','Andrew Test',"en")

sub do_register_email_list {
# (email,name,lang)

    use WWW::Curl::Easy;
    use Digest::MD5;
    use JSON;

    my @name = split /\s+/, $_[1];
    my $apikey = 'xxxx-us6';
    my $listid = 'xxxx';
    my $email = $_[0];
    my $endpoint = "https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists";
    my $lang = $_[2]||'en';

    my $json = JSON::encode_json({
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status'        => 'pending',
        'language' => $lang,
        'merge_fields'  => {
            'FNAME'     => $name[0]||'',
            'LNAME'     => $name[1]||''
        }
    });

    my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;

    my $url = "$endpoint/$listid/members/" . Digest::MD5::md5(lc($email));

    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $url);

#    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apikey);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json',"Accept-Language: $lang"]);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

    # A filehandle, reference to a scalar or reference to a typeglob can be used here.
    my $response_body;
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);

    # Starts the actual request
    my $retcode = $curl->perform;

#print "FOO HERE";
    # Looking at the results...
    if ($retcode == 0) {
        print "Transfer went ok\n";
        my $response_code = $curl->getinfo(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        print "Received response: $response_body\n";
    } else {
        # Error code, type of error, error message
        print "An error happened: $retcode ".$curl->strerror($retcode)." ".$curl->errbuf."\n";
    }
}
```

Hopefully this saves someone else from all the grief I had with it :) (the MailChimp support lady also said she will get their team to add something about this in the developer notes, so its made a bit clearer!)

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the [source](https://metacpan.org/source/ARCANEZ/WWW-Mailchimp-0.010/lib/WWW/Mailchimp.pm), it defaults to API 1.3:

```
has api_version => (
  is => 'ro',
  isa => Num,
  lazy => 1,
  default => sub { 1.3 },
);
```

The documentation for that [shows](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php) you need to use MC_LANGUAGE:

> string    MC_LANGUAGE Set the member's language preference. Supported
>   codes are fully case-sensitive and can be found [here](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/can-i-see-what-languages-my-subscribers-use#code).

It looks like the module just shoves whatever data structure you provide into JSON and POSTs it to Mailchimp, so the appropriate Mailchimp API doc version for the API you target should be referenced as a primary source.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Doing this doesn't seem to do it though (the confirmation still comes in as english): `$mailchimp->listSubscribe( id => "75a6bfd589", email_address => $in->{Email}, merge_vars => [ FNAME => $name[0], LNAME => $name[1], MC_LANGUAGE => "fr" ] );` ... any ideas?

Comment: Mmm there must be something up with the 1.3 API. Even FNAME and LNAME are not getting passed in using: `merge_vars => [ FNAME => 'xxxx', LNAME => 'yxxx', MC_LANGUAGE => "fr" ]`. Maybe I'll give it another go tomorrow, but add some debug into the MailChimp.pm file, so I can see what request is actually being called (looks like it'd be worth moving to v3.0 as well, as 1.3 and 2.0 look like they are being depreciated anyway :))

Comment: Ok, so it looks like its a LOT more tricky than I was hoping!  I've no got: `https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe.json?apikey=xxxx&id=xxxx&email[email]=xxxx&merge_vars[FNAME]=John&merge_vars[LNAME]=Doe&merge_vars[MC_LANGUAGE]=fr` ... however, it still ignores the language :/ I'm going to see if I can find a specific MailChimp forum, to try and ask whats going on